# query that returns results not in a certain table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This query below selects all parts(partId) and catalogs(catalogId) used by week(weekId) for a particular buildID

--Each build has a set of catalogs and catalog parts.

```
select bw.weekId, epl.catalogId, wep.logId, epl.id, wep.partId, c.catalogName, cp.partName
            from engine.thisWeeksEngineParts wep
            inner join engine.EnginePartsList epl  ON wep.logId = epl.Id
            inner join engine.buildWeek bw ON epl.weekId = bw.weekId
            inner join engine.catalog c ON epl.catalogId = c.catalogId
            inner join engine.catalogParts cp ON wep.partId = cp.partId
            where bw.buildID = 1994334936
            order by weekId, catalogId, partId
```

Now I'd like to have an inverse query that shows me the opposite of the query above.  So instead of selecting all the catalogs and parts used by week for a buildID, I'd like to see all the parts in each catalog that were NOT used for a buildID.

So I still want to see the catalogs, but I want to see all the unused parts in those catalogs.

I tried using a right join on engine.catalogParts but that just returns the same number of results.

Here are the table definitions for the catalog and catalogParts tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [engine].[catalogParts](
    [partId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [catalogId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [partName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_catalogParts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 


CREATE TABLE [engine].[catalog](
    [catalogId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [buildId] [int] NULL,
    [catalogName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [discriminator] [char](3) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [pk_catalog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Example data:

Here is an example that shows 3 different parts from a catalog used in week 101 using my first query:

```
weekId | catalogId | logId | id | partId | catalogName | partName
101          11        66    66     29       V6_Eng       piston_01
101          11        66    66     40       V6_Eng       ring_00a
101          11        66    66     77       V6_Eng       valve_202194
```

What I want the new query to show, is all the parts NOT used in week 101, so something like this:

```
weekId | catalogId | logId | id | partId | catalogName | partName
101          11        66    66     29       V6_Eng       manifold_upper_44
101          11        66    66     40       V6_Eng       manifod_lower_44c
101          11        66    66     77       V6_Eng       camshaft_229
```

Thanks!

Comment: Removed the tag bomb on SQL Server products.  Please edit your question and tag the correct version you're actually using.

Comment: how are catalog and catalogParts linked?

Comment: @Siyual Thanks! I switch between sql server 2005, sql-server 2008r2 and 2012 depending on which server and build(dev, staging, production). Eventually we hope to move everything to SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @Quassnoi they are linked by catalogID

Comment: @999cm999: I don't see `catalogParts.catalogId` in your query, it's joined on something else. Could you please post your tables' definitions?

Comment: @Quassnoi I joined engine.catalogParts on engine.thisWeeksEngineParts because that tells me what parts are used in a weeks build. However I still need catalogParts so I can get get the catalogParts.partName field. How do I post a table definition? Do you mean all the stuff when you type 'sp_help yourtablename'? Thanks

Comment: @999cm999: right-click on the table name, select `Generate Scripts` and post the output here (just the `CREATE TABLE` bits)

Comment: @Quassnoi Ok thanks.  I added those 2 tables.  thanks again.

Comment: catalog left join catalog parts where partid is null? is that what you're looking for

Comment: from what I see, parts can be in a build either through `catalog` or through `thisWeeksEngineParts`. Which of those are considered not being in a build? Could you please post some sample data and desired resultset?

Comment: @Quassnoi I added example results for both my existing query and for my new query.  Thanks!

Comment: @999cm999: you link your weeks using two tables, `thisWeeksEngineParts` and `EnginePartsList`. One of them links catalog, another one links parts directly. So what happens if a part is used through the list but not through catalog - thisWeek? or vice versa?

Comment: @Quassnoi thisWeeksEngineParts just contains a logId(id to EnginePartsList) and a partId.  EnginePartsList contains a weekId and catalogId.

Comment: @999cm999: yes, I noticed. This does not answer my question, though.

Comment: @Quassnoi oh sorry, when a builder is using the system, it writes that session data to the table thisWeeksEngineParts. So when the builder selects a part , it inserts that partId into that table. I hope that helps.

Comment: @999cm999: sorry, it does not help much. What's a builder? What's a session data?

Comment: @Quassnoi the builder is the person using the system. The session data is all the data from when they are using the system. The parts they choose and stuff like that...

Comment: @Scotch Do you mean: left join engine.catalogParts WHERE partId IS NULL? Thanks

Comment: @999cm999 I see that you're joining `thisWeeksEngineParts` to `catalogParts`. Does `EnginePartsList` also have a `partId` to join to `catalogParts`?